# Refer to a value inside of an exists sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a query that uses a sub-query. When the sub-query returns a value I want to return that value, if sub-query returns nothing I want to return today's date. The problem is that when the sub-query has a value I don't know how to refer to the column I want to return. In this case effDate:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN exists(SELECT TOP 1 pp.Period_End_Date [effDate]
FROM Employee ee WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN PayPlanner pp WITH (NOLOCK) ON ee.ClientID = pp.ClientID
    AND ee.PaygroupUID = pp.PaygroupUID
WHERE ee.ClientID = 85845
    AND pp.ClientID = 85845
    AND ee.EmpUID = 133066325953730
    AND ee.m_eff_end_date IS NULL
    AND pp.m_eff_end_date IS NULL
    AND pp.Payroll_Status IN ('E','I')
    AND pp.Date_Type IN ('R','A')
ORDER BY Period_End_Date) then ???HOW TO ACCESS effDate HERE???
ELSE GETDATE()
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access columns in those subqueries.  You seem to want the maximum date -- if it exists -- or the current date.  Instead, use an aggregation query with `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(pp.Period_End_Date), GETDATE()) as [effDate]
FROM Employee ee WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN PayPlanner pp WITH (NOLOCK) ON ee.ClientID = pp.ClientID
    AND ee.PaygroupUID = pp.PaygroupUID
WHERE ee.ClientID = 85845
    AND pp.ClientID = 85845
    AND ee.EmpUID = 133066325953730
    AND ee.m_eff_end_date IS NULL
    AND pp.m_eff_end_date IS NULL
    AND pp.Payroll_Status IN ('E', 'I')
    AND pp.Date_Type IN ('R', 'A')
```

Note:  Your query seems to want the minimum period end date.  I would actually expect the maximum.  But in any case, the aggregation function is `MIN()`.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of one of those ClientIDs in the `WHERE` since you are doing an `INNER JOIN`, they will always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to encapsulate the EXISTS subquery in COALESCE instead:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(( SELECT TOP 1
                            pp.Period_End_Date [effDate]
                   FROM     Employee ee WITH ( NOLOCK )
                            INNER JOIN PayPlanner pp WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON ee.ClientID = pp.ClientID
                                                              AND ee.PaygroupUID = pp.PaygroupUID
                   WHERE    ee.ClientID = 85845
                            AND pp.ClientID = 85845
                            AND ee.EmpUID = 133066325953730
                            AND ee.m_eff_end_date IS NULL
                            AND pp.m_eff_end_date IS NULL
                            AND pp.Payroll_Status IN ( 'E', 'I' )
                            AND pp.Date_Type IN ( 'R', 'A' )
                   ORDER BY Period_End_Date
                 ), GETDATE());
```